# Insertar información sin que se permita insertar más de una vez un mismo valor (Lista simplemente enlazada Java)

Tags: java, lista, nodos

Muy Buenas con todos. Por favor ayúdenme con la parte en la que no se permite ingresar el mismo valor ya que el código para insertar lo tengo hecho pero no se que modificar exactamente para evitar la repetición de información. Muchas gracias de antemano.

```
public class Lista {
Nodo primero;
public Lista() {
    this.primero = null;
}
boolean insertarObject(Object info) {
    try {
        if (this.primero == null) {
            this.primero = new Nodo(info);
            return true;
        }
        Nodo aux = this.primero;
        while (aux.siguiente != null) {
            aux = aux.siguiente;
        }
        aux.siguiente = new Nodo(info);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Durante la inserción, recorres la lista. Te bastaría con comprobar si existe el valor en la lista mientras la recorres, y salir en caso de que sí:

```
public class Lista {
    Nodo primero;
    public Lista() {
      this.primero = null;
    }
    boolean insertarObject(Object info) {
        try {
            if (this.primero == null) {
                this.primero = new Nodo(info);
                return true;
            }
            Nodo aux = this.primero;
            while (aux.siguiente != null) {
                aux = aux.siguiente;
                if (aux.getInfo().equals(info)) return true;
            }
            aux.siguiente = new Nodo(info);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
    }
}
```